# Twitter id to screen name

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I have the following code to request a twitter user by ID:

```
request.get( {
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=' + userIds,
    oauth: {
            consumer_key: 'KEys',
            consumer_secret: 'are',
            access_token: 'here',
            access_token_secret: ''
          }
   }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(json);
       }
});
```

What do I do next to extract screen name of the twitter user?

Comment: The `users/lookup` endpoint is to request up to 100 users in bulk. You said you "request a twitter user by ID". If you want only one user, use [`users/show`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show.html) instead. Anyway, your variable is named plural, who it's unclear what you're looking for. Also, use a [Twitter library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-lite) rather than the bloated `request` module.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this with the help of enumerations or loop. It will give you the user name of the tweet extracted.

```
for u in users
    print u.screen_name
```

Comment: The question was about JavaScript, not (incorrect) Python.